# How do I view object properties in PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, view, propertygrid, expand

At the moment I have an object of type A which is being viewed by the PropertyGrid. However, one of its properties is of type B. The property which is of type B is not expandable. How can I change this so that:

a) I can expand custom object property's
b) Those changes are bound to that property

Here is the code I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace PropGridTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            A a = new A
            {
                Foo = "WOO HOO!",
                Bar = 10,
                BooFar = new B
                {
                    FooBar = "HOO WOO!",
                    BarFoo = 100
                }
            };

            propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = a;
        }
    }
    public class A
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }
        public int Bar { get; set; }
        public B BooFar { get; set; }
    }
    public class B
    {
        public string FooBar { get; set; }
        public int BarFoo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the [`ExpandableObjectConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter.aspx) class for this purpose.

> This class adds support for properties
>   on an object to the methods and
>   properties provided by TypeConverter.
>   To make a type of property expandable
>   in the PropertyGrid, specify this
>   TypeConverter for standard
>   implementations of
>   GetPropertiesSupported and
>   GetProperties.

To use this converter, decorate the property in question with the [**`TypeConverterAttribute`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute.aspx), with `typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter)` as the constructor-argument.

```
public class A
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public B BooFar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works exactly how I needed it to. I can't mark your answer as correct for 8 minutes or so though...but I will :D

Comment: Oh Great, that was exactly what i needed and search for an hour.